# Livy Client - Spark_Conf.zip does not exist

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hortonworks-data-platform, livy

I am trying to submit the application through livy batches through the Postman POST call. I do see the following error in the logs. But i am able to execute the commands in the interactive livy sessions through Curl.

I checked the HADOOP_CONF_DIR property in livy2-env and i set the same value as Spark2-env

Please suggest if i am missing any

`"Diagnostics: File does not exist: hdfs://<host:port>/user/livy/.sparkStaging/application_TimeStamp/__spark_conf__.zip"`

Comment: Livy needs to know where `${SPARK_HOME}/conf` is

Comment: Thank you for responding. I have checked the configuration and i see the following            
SPARK_HOME=/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client
SPARK_CONF_DIR=/etc/spark2/conf
.But i could see the link in the /etc/spark2/conf pointing to the Spark Config. Please suggest

Comment: Not sure, really. I haven't ran a version of HDP that supports Spark2 + Livy. You might want to try the Hotronworks support forums

Answer (score 0):

You need to set path of all the hdfs files containing folder at  `HADOOP_CONF_DIR`. In my system the path is `/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop`. Just check in yours and set it. I hope it'll work.